# How to hide the my source code in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried the following formulas to hide the codes of my project in Google Chrome and my codes are hidden, but when I close my project and open it again, the process returns to the beginning and my codes are not hidden.
How Can I Solve This?

```
scripts: {
      "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"
    }
```

and

env file:

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

Comment: You cannot hide JS code that is delivered to the front-end. The best you can do is obfuscate it.

Comment: Typically, the minimizer provides reasonable obfuscation.

Answer (score 2):

Completely hiding client-side JS code is practically not possible at present. However, you can try these things to make stealing/understanding your code a bit more difficult.

- use cross-env to inject environment variables
- obfuscate your code using javascript obfuscation tools
- disable right click .. etc.

Good luck!

Comment: tnx for answer, How can I do this or are there any resources?

Comment: 1. [javascript-obfuscator](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator)

2. [jscrambler](https://docs.jscrambler.com/code-integrity/frameworks-and-libraries/react) - Looks like this is paid one!
3. There are few npm packages available to target sensitive data areas: email, phone name, email ..etc

Keep in mind, obfuscation is a bit expensive operation. So, apply it on smaller portion of the code instead of whole app.. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to hide your front-ends source code. JavaScript is something called interpreted language, which essentially means, that it compiles at runtime, so you have to give your browser source code to for your website to work, the only thing you can do is to build it in the way, that it's extremely hard to read, but never completely hide.